# Number lines - How to change the direction of the numbers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I've been using LaTeX for about 3 days. Most of it is quite intuitive but I've been really struggling to get a suitable number line to answer a question in my maths course.

The code below has been taken from another forum, but I have tried to adapt it to my maths question.

I essentially want to show a number line from 55m to 229m.

When I try this code it puts the information in backwards! E.g from 250m - 50m.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=-0.05]  
\draw[very thick] (55,0) -- (229,0); %black line  
\path [draw=black, fill=black] (55,0) circle (50pt); %black circle  
\path [draw=black, fill=white, thick] (229,0.0) circle (50pt); %white circle  
\draw[latex-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (300.5,0) ; %range/width (arrow)  
\foreach \x in  {50,100,150,200,250}%vertical lines (adding)  
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,60pt) -- (0pt,-60pt); %verical lines (angle)  
\foreach \x in {50,100,150,200,250}%ACTUAL NUMBERS  
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] %horizontal line  
{$\x$};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Your scaling factor is negative, this will mirror everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A negative scaling factor will mirror up and down, and left and right.
- The circle filled white has to be drawn after the lines, otherwise the lines will cross it.

There is a potential pitfall with choosing the actual numbers and then scaling the graph down: As TeX uses small integers, it may quickly happen that there is an overflow. Whenever you get an error message about `dimension too large`, you have to downscale your coordinates by hand.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.05]
\draw[latex-latex] (-0.5,0) -- (300.5,0) ; %range/width (arrow)  
\foreach \x in  {50,100,150,200,250}
   \draw (\x,3) -- (\x,-3) node[below]{$\x$};
\draw[very thick] (55,0) -- (229,0); %black line  
\draw[fill] (55,0) circle (2) ; %black circle  
\draw[fill=white, thick] (229,0.0) circle (2); %white circle  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, that worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the advice.